# Windows authentication across trusted domains on an IIS intranet site

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, cross-domain

We have an intranet site that uses Windows Authentication (Running on IIS 7.5). Anyone on our domain (let's call it Domain1) can access the intranet using their Windows credentials. However, we recently set up a trust between our parent company's domain (let's call it ParentDomain) and our domain.

However, no one from the ParentDomain domain can access the intranet using their Windows credentials. I'm not sure what sort of configuration I am supposed to do in IIS to allow ParentDomain users to access the intranet site.

If someone could point me in the right direction to get this set up, that would be great!

Thanks.